# Date.parse(2/4/2011 9:34:48 AM)

Tags: javascript, date

my input will be from a variable (Ticket.CreationDate) and will look like

2/4/2011 9:34:48 AM (it will vary of course)

Ideally I could pass in the variable as-is and get the different results
like
unknownDateFunc(Ticket.DateCreation) \ Outputs= Friday, February 4, 2011
unknownTimeFunc(Ticket.DateCreation) \ Outputs= 9:34 AM

Meddling with Date.parse() and .toDateString()
and I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Will your input always have the same format?

Comment: Yes but the date and time will of course vary so mm/dd  and hh will sometimes have 1 digit and sometimes 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a combination of 2 different Date libraries I am aware of.

The first, for parsing the date from a string, is DateJS.  You can find it at http://www.datejs.com/.  Your example parses with their library fine (once you include appropriate quote marks)

```
// Results in Date object whose toString is:  
//    Fri Feb 04 2011 09:34:48 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
Date.parse('2/4/2011 9:34:48 AM')
```

The other library is for creating nicely formatted string values based on your date object.  This can be found at http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format.  For example, from that page:

```
// Saturday, June 9th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM
var now = new Date();
dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
```

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you have a static format makes a solution simple.

```
var dateReg = 
    /(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})\s*(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\s*(AM|PM)/;
function parseDate(input) {
    var year, month, day, hour, minute, second,
        result = dateReg.exec(input);
    if (result) {
        year = +result[3];
        month = +result[1]-1; //added -1 to correct for the zero-based months
        day = +result[2];
        hour = +result[4];
        minute = +result[5];
        second = +result[6];
        if (result[7] === 'PM' && hour !== 12) {
            hour += 12;
        }       
    }
    return new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
}
```

Comment: So after this is returned what would I do to display Friday, February 4, 2011?

Comment: It should be noted that month is 0 based index so you have to subtract 1 from result[1].

Answer (score -3):

Create a function which takes date and in-format string and out-format string as parameter

```
string FormatDate(string date, string informat,string outformat)
{
    var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
    return DateTime.ParseExact(date, informat, culture).ToString(outformat);
}

FormatDate("2/4/2011 9:34:48 AM","M/d/yyyy H:m:s tt","H:m:s")               //9:34:48
```

You can get different format string from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Comment: This is not javascript