# How can set meridiem(AM or PM) into a date using by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date, momentjs

I want to set Hours and minutes and milliseconds and meridian into a date

```
var newdate = new Date();
var splitedDate = context.timesheetlist.StartTime.split(":")//Start time is 03:45:28 AM
newdate.setHours(splitedDate[0]);// added hours
newdate.setMinutes(splitedDate[1]);// added minutes
```

But I don't know how I can add the meridian (`AM` or `PM`) in to the `newdate`  object?

I did't found a valuable solution in any websites, i am using **moment.js**.

Is it possible way to solve this problem in `moment.js` or `angular.js` or `javascript` or `jquery`?

Comment: The date object is always in 24 hour format, hence it does not have the meridiem. AM/PM is only required when the date is coerced to a string.

Comment: you could add the current date as string to your time string (e.g. 05/18/2015 03:45:28 AM) and parse the whole string as date again. You will find a lot of examples for this, e.g.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034642/date-parse2-4-2011-93448-am

Comment: I got the answer, I will post it latter..  Anyway thanks for your valuable comments.....