# How can I convert a string to a Datetime object?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am dealing with an old database. I need to compare dates to each other. One date type is `datetime` and the other is a `string`.

When I try to convert

```
07/25/2019 06:30AM
```

using `new Date(Date.parse(07/25/2019 06:30AM))`

I get the error Invalid Date.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date i think it helps you

Comment: The usual suggestion is [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date.parse(2/4/2011 9:34:48 AM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034642/date-parse2-4-2011-93448-am)

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date('07/25/2019 06:30 AM')
```

but your date format is invalid because it requires space between time (`06:30`) and `AM`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
new Date(Date.parse("07/25/2019 06:30"))
```

You don't need the AM that is redundant to the fact of the time itself of 06.
I can see using that if you were to use 6:30 but not 06:30.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by two ways:

- Remove AM:

```
    let dt = new Date('07/25/2019 06:30');
    alert(dt);
```

- Add space between hour and AM:

```
    let dt = new Date('07/25/2019 06:30 AM');
    alert(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following approach to to avoid [some strange bugs while parse Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results):

```
let date_string = "07/25/2019 06:30 AM"
let [M,d,y,h,m,s] = date_string.split(/[/ :]/);
h = (s == 'AM') ? h : (parseInt(h) + 12);    
let yourDate =  new Date(y, parseInt(M)-1, d, h, parseInt(m));
console.log(`yourDate ${yourDate}`);
```